# creating subfolders for every category on classifieds website

Tags: php, wordpress, web, categories, subdirectory

i'm in the process of creating a classifieds website.

the website has a search functionality to filter by location.

at the moment i am simply using the php GET function to send the location through the url and retrieve it before searching the database.

i would prefer to be able to have the location come up as a subfolder of the domain.

is this possible without uploading a physical subfolder and index.php file for every location?

please advise on the best options for achieving this.

Comment: Check out [this SO Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115629/simplest-php-routing-framework) regarding routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help Kovge.

After taking your answer and doing some further research I have created a RewriteRule which fits my requirements perfectly.

Since the locations are in a structure that there is multiple levels (for State, Area, City, Suburb etc.) I have made it so it doesn't matter how many subfolders deep the URL is, the return will only be the final subfolder (without the trailing slash).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?(.*[^/])/?$ /index.php?location=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
Try the apache mod_rewrite:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

turn it on, and in the .htaccess file (must be the same folder with your index.php):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase / # or the subfolder where your index.php is inside the domain
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?location=$1
```

And an example for index.php:

```
<?php 
   print $_GET['location']; 
?>
```

This may helps you.